# Screen share with sharing controls to participants in Agora IO

Tags: screensharing, agora.io

Is it possible to create a video conference web app with screen sharing option that allows to edit the file or document or do some actions in some application for all participants of the conference.
For example I hosted a video conference and want that all participants interact with some file or application. How to do that with agora.io? Or may be other instruments?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is very much possible. Agora only provides the video and voice part, you would need a separate service to handle the document.

The functionality you are describing is similar to the [Agora BOX plugin](https://app.box.com/services/agora-box-demo). Users can open a document through BOX's web-app using the Agora plugin and it opens a video call with a shared document.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is the whiteboarding feature. Agora is actually working with third parties to have features like whiteboarding features that allow users to take notes online and share powerpoints.

You can try out this web demo: https://solutions.agora.io/education/web/#/

Is it something you are looking for?